# How to check expired date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a date column in this format: `'2687-12-31 00:00:00.000'`.

When I try to check for the expired date in this column:

```
import datetime
new_df = original_df[(original_df["RecordEndDate"] > datetime.datetime.now())]
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

and when I try to convert the format using:

```
original_df['RecordEndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(original_df['RecordEndDate'], 
                                              format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2687-12-31 00:00:00.000' doesn't match format specified
```

Any idea?

Comment: try changing `format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` to `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

Comment: Same error :( `ValueError: time data '2687-12-31 00:00:00.000' doesn't match format specified`

Comment: show all code, what you do

Comment: This is really interesting! I get a valid timestamp for `pd.to_datetime('2262-04-11 00:00:00.000', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`, but an error for `pd.to_datetime('2262-04-12 00:00:00.000', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`. Bug in Pandas perhaps?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I don't really know how I feel, excited or frustrated lol

Comment: @VolArt It's a Jupyter Notebook, not really a code

Comment: the timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited
 1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225 to 2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807

Comment: @GovindParashar ah, it had to be something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lambda to catch the exception.

```
arr = pd.Series(['2687-12-31 00:00:00.000', '2007-12-3'])
def func(d):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(d) > pd.datetime.now()
    except ValueError:
        return True

arr[arr.apply(lambda v: func(v))]

0    2687-12-31 00:00:00.000
dtype: object
```

The problem arises because the max time in pandas is somewhere till the year 2262.

```
pd.Timestamp.max
OUT[1]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

Comment: +1. Note that with a less exotic, datetime format, eg `pd.to_datetime('2262-04-12')`, Pandas will return a more helpful `OutOfBoundsDatetimeError`. The combination of the unusual year with milliseconds is niche enough that you just get a `ValueError`.